# How do I adjust the color balance on a Nikon D300?

Tags: nikon, white-balance, color-management, color-filters

First of all let me clarify here. I am aware of the color balance feature on the Nikon D300 and I generally use Auto, so this isn't about that aspect of color balance.

My camera has a tendency to shoot a little magenta and I am wondering if there is a way to modify that in the control panel. If not, I can accept a no, but it would be nice to not have to continually adjust all my photos.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you shoot RAW or JPEG? What do you use to post process on the computer?

Comment: Add a touch of green filter. BUT if this is consistent it may be a fault. Is your monitor correctly calibrated? Custom white balance with a white card or white object helps but auto should be good enough for many things.

Comment: I shoot RAW and process the images through ImageIntester Pro.

Comment: The monitor is calibrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Since you shoot RAW. Color-balance has no effect on your photos.** If they come out the wrong color, blame the RAW processor or its operator ;)

To adjust color-balance of the *preview* along the Green-Magenta axis go to the camera menu and find the WB Fine-Tuning screen.

To adjust it along the Amber-Blue axis, hold the WB button and turn the sub-command dial (usually the front control-dial but they can be swapped).

Comment: I agree. If you shoot RAW... your camera isn't at fault, it is your RAW processing software. Really it is the same as if your camera didn't even give white balance a value, it is the responsibility of the software.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. What menu is the WB Fine-Tuning Screen under?

Comment: Under the camera menu, IIRC you have to scroll down to the second page. Select the WB first and then (I think) press the right arrow. It should be easy to find in the user-manual now that you know what this is called.

Comment: Hi Itai, I found it in the D300 manual page 130. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, ignore color balance on camera, since you shoot RAW. Instead, be sure to shoot a [white balance reference](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=grey%20cards&N=0&InitialSearch=yes) at each location. Then, you can use the reference within your photo processing software to easily adjust white balance.

I posted a note on my [photoblog with instructions on how to do this in Lightroom.](http://digitalmason.posterous.com/my-white-balance-workflow-in-lightroom)